# Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty

Tags: google-api, recaptcha

Tengo un problema ya que no carga la casilla de verificación en la página, revisando en la consola del explorador, me da el siguiente mensaje:

```
Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty recaptcha__es_419.js:533:277
eK https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:533
nE https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:530
forEach self-hosted:266
nE https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:530
$A https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:527
uy https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:521
<anonymous> https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:536
<anonymous> https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1558333958099/recaptcha__es_419.js:556
```

​
Esto se esta integrando en un formulario simple para su previa verificación a envio, como adicional esta lo siguiente:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

Y dentro del formulario:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key-data">
```

¿Que solución consideran puede aplicar en base a su experiencia?

Comment: Gabo. Por favor agrega más información sobre el código HTML, JS, PHP o Java que estás desarrollando. Simplemente con el error no podemos hacer mucho...

Comment: De hecho es un simple HTML, y agregue el código de integración para el reCaptcha, no hay mayor complejidad, solo es para verificar antes de enviar un formulario simple de texto.

Comment: No estás cargando la librería dos veces? Creo que ese error generalmente aparece por eso.

Comment: No, esta la etiqueta solo una vez!, por eso me pareció rarisimo, con otras paginas no tengo problema, pero no le encuentro solución

Comment: Encontré el error, sucede que la etiqueta <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key-data"> no esta cerrada y es por esta razón que marca el error! agradezco tu atención Chong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré el error, sucede que la etiqueta:

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key-data">`

no esta cerrada y es por esta razón que marca el error, lo correcto es:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key-data"></div>
```